# SQL Summation with more than one Condition

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
Link  PeriodiD Debit   Credit  Project
1      49       -       200     1
1      49       200     -       2
1      49       100             0 
1      50       50      -       1
2      49        -      600     0
```

I want a script to sum the debit and credit per link per period disregarding project.

so the answer should look like

```
Link  PeriodiD TotalDebit   TotalCredit
1      49       300          200     
1      50       50           -           
2      49       -            600
```

i have more than 60 periodID and more than 100 link.

Please assist to make such a script

Comment: You should look into `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Group by with aggregate functions.

```
SELECT Link,
       PeriodID,
       SUM(TotalDebit) AS TotalDebit,
       SUM(TotalCredit) AS TotalCredit
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Link, PeriodId;
```

This query might not always give the expected result if you can have NULL values, depending on the DBMS that you use. You can modify it like this to account for this situation:

```
SELECT Link,
       PeriodID,
       SUM(COALESCE(TotalDebit,0)) AS TotalDebit,
       SUM(COALESCE(TotalCredit,0)) AS TotalCredit
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Link, PeriodId;
```

Comment: Hi @smucheke. You should accept this answer as the correct answer if it answers your question.